# Enforcing class call sequence requirements

Tags: c++, oop

I'm trying to design a class that encapsulates the processing of some data, the caching of the results, and access to the results via member functions.

My current design is something like the following:

```
class DataProcessor
{
public:
    DataProcessor();
    void populateUsing(const rawDataSource &source);

    // Must call populateUsing() first!
    int getDataX() const;
    int getDataY() const;
};
```

There is also an additional constraint: the lifetime of the supplied `rawDataSource` is such that it may become invalid in between the call to `populateUsing()` and `getData[XY]()`

Before reaching this design, I went through various alternatives, including:

1. Passing in the `rawDataSource` argument to the constructor
2. Having a private `isPopulated` flag, which is checked by `getDataX()` etc, which could then either throw an exception, return an error value, or call `populateUsing()` itself.

Alternative 1 works, but wasn't adequate as the processing may take a long time and may not actually be necessary if `getData[XY]()` aren't called. I wanted to perform the processing on demand.

Alternative 2 wasn't adequate as:

- I can't throw an exception in this code without causing major headaches (and ugly usage)
- Returning an error code might be possible but would require an ugly rearrangement of parameters to allow the error code to be passed
- `populateUsing()` couldn't be called because the `rawDataSource` was not guaranteed to still be valid

My overall objective is to provide a class interface that is easy to use and difficult to misuse. Enforcing a member function call order with nothing but a comment seems to violate my 'difficult to misuse' objective.

What's the preferred design given my constraints? Feel free to nominate one of my alternatives if you've found that to be the best in practice.

(Would this question be better posted to programmers.SE?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think really my class should simply be like this:

```
class DataProcessor
{
private:
    // Moved to private. Now called by the constructor.
    void populateUsing(const rawDataSource &source);

public:
    DataProcessor(const rawDataSource &source);

    int getDataX() const;
    int getDataY() const;
};
```

The reason for having `populateUsing()` as a public function was to allow flexibility of when the (possibly intensive) processing was to occur.

However, the caller can still control the time of processing by simply creating the `DataProcessor` object when it is needed (or when the required rawDataSource is valid).

Answer (score 2):

Considering your two main "goals"

> I'm trying to design a class that encapsulates the processing of some
>   data, the caching of the results, and access to the results via member
>   functions.

and

> My overall objective is to provide a class interface that is easy to
>   use and difficult to misuse. Enforcing a member function call order
>   with nothing but a comment seems to violate my 'difficult to misuse'
>   objective.

I would prevent the client from all the decisions and evaluations.

What about

```
class DataProcessor {

public:

    int getDataX(const rawDataSource &source);   // Probably you should rename the methods
    int getDataY(const rawDataSource &source);
};
```

---

```
int DataProccessor::getDataX(const rawDataSource &source) {
   // Process data if not already cached and valid
   // return cached data
}

int DataProccessor::getDataY(const rawDataSource &source) {
   // Process data if not already cached and valid
   // return cached data
}
```

This way you just process the data if needed. You're able to check if your data has already been processed and is still valid.

Comment: This might work for others with similar design requirements. For my case, however, the rawDataSource object is not available at the times where getData[XY] is called.